# Making a print function repeat on a new line everytime it prints

Tags: printing, repeat

So I want this final print function to print its function on a new line every time it prints. I've tried various "\n" placements to make it work but to no avail. Any tips?

```
from datetime import date
currentYear = date.today().year


print('Hi. What is your name?')
name = input()

while True:
    try:

        print('How old are you, ' + name + '?')
        age = int(input())

        if age >= 0:
            break

        else:
             print('That is not a valid number.')
    except ValueError:
        print('That is not a valid number')

 ageinHundred = 100 - int(age)
y = currentYear + int(ageinHundred)
t = 'You will be 100 years old in the year ' + str(int((y)))

print(t)

print('Give me another number')
num = input()

f = (int(num) * t)

print(f)
```

I want the final print function (print(f)) to print f multiple times on a new line each time. Not one after the other like the above code does now.
Thanks!

Comment: It should always start on a new line since every other print is newline terminated. Did you try `print("\n", f)` though?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I did! It unfortunately didn’t work but honestly from what little knowledge I have of python I figured it would. Very dumbfounded. Currently it prints the f function without new lines and just repeated one after the other

Comment: That means you must have either redefined `print` somewhere to be a print that strip newlines, or the console you're printing to is screwed. As is (and definitely with the change I recomended), `f` should print on a new line each time. I don't think we'll be able to help until you include more information, like the desired output, what you're actually getting, and what console you're printing to.

Comment: @Carcigenicate the desired output is to print f on a new line every time. So it would just be f printed out on a separate line for however many times the user input. So if I entered 5 it would print the function f, five times. It does this currently, but I can’t get the \n function to work in making it appear on a new line after every print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last couple of lines to:

```
# Put t inside a list so it does list multiplication instead
#  of string multiplication
f = int(num) * [t]

# Then join the individual f-lists with newlines and print
print("\n".join(f))
```

For the `f =` line, inspect `f` to get a better idea of what's going on there.

For the `join` part, `join` takes a list of strings, inserts the given string (in this case `"\n"`; a newline), and "joins" it all together. Get used to using `join`. It is a very helpful function.

Comment: This worked! I wouldn't have thought of that solution but I am still trying to learn. Appreciate the help! Hoping I can come up with solutions like that for myself in the future.

Comment: @Austin Again, practice using `join`. As soon as you understand it fully, you'll realize that you can use it in many places to clean up code.

Comment: I have read a little about using join but haven't used it much yet. It seems like it is something I'll have to practice more with. I had pretty much tried using every variation of \n so you really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from datetime import date
currentYear = date.today().year

print('Hi. What is your name?')
name = input()

while True:
    try:

        print('How old are you, ' + name + '?')
        age = int(input())

        if age >= 0:
            break

        else:
             print('That is not a valid number.')
    except ValueError:
        print('That is not a valid number')

ageinHundred = 100 - int(age)
y = currentYear + int(ageinHundred)
t = 'You will be 100 years old in the year ' + str(int((y)))

print(t)

print('Give me another number')
num = input()

for i in range(0,int(num)):
    print(t)
```

Comment: This worked, also! This is the solution I was going to try and do for myself but I couldn't figure out what to do with the input inside of range(). Thanks!